# React lookup tables: files vs. queries?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, file-io

I'm writing a ReactJS solution that requires a large number (50+) of 'lookup-up' tables. The tables themselves are relatively small (<1000 rows) and are updated in an external system, relatively infrequently.

I just wanted to get an idea of the pros and cons of implementing them as files to import versus queries run against an existing Postgres instance (which is not the source of truth in this instance). I'm veering towards files, because referencing would be synchronous, and the updates are irregular. But I just wanted to make sure that I was not missing something in terms of performance, security, resource, or simplicity arguments.

Additionally, my import approach was simply to import an array of records (objects) for each table, and then use an `Array.find()` on them. Is there are better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what the data storage issue has to do with React. I think you need to break down your problem further (data storage, frontend/backend data querying, and data rendering) before formulating your question.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I agree. I have a working React solution, with a Postgres backend already (hence ‘existing‘). I just wanted to know if there were any reasons not to implement these lookups as files, instead of tying them in via yet more asynchronous calls.